Create slots for v-combobox vuetify
I have a component that I want to create a slot for v-combobox because I want to show the dropdown items as a custom style section ,


      <v-combobox
            v-model="select"
            v-model:search="search"
            :items='companyList'
            item-title='company_name'
            item-value='id'
            density="compact"
            label="start chat with related companies"
            variant="outlined"
            bg-color='navbar'
            hide-details
            single-line
            @input="startConversation"
          >
            <template #item="{ index, props, item }">
              <v-list-item v-bind="props" :key="index" @click="createRoom(item)">
                <div class='flex flex-col gap-y-1'>
                  <!-- Company Name -->
                  <span>{{ item.company_name }}</span>

                  <!-- Staff Names (Name and Last Name) -->
                  <div v-if="item.staff && item.staff.length">
          <span v-for="(staffMember, i) in item.staff" :key="i">
            {{ staffMember.name }} {{ staffMember.last_name }}
          </span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Fallback if no staff -->
                  <div v-else>
                    <span>No staff available</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </v-list-item>
            </template>
          </v-combobox>



I want to show slots as a custom template in dropdown when I'm searching in v-combobox, My data is like :


[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "company_name": "company name",
        "staff": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "name1",
                "last_name": "lastname1",
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "avatar": "https://test.com",
                "position": "ceo",
                "languages": [],
                "phone_number": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "name2",
                "last_name": "lastname2",
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "avatar": "https://test.com",
                "position": "ceo",
                "languages": [],
                "phone_number": ""
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "name3",
                "last_name": "lastname3",
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "avatar": "https://test.com",
                "position": "ceo",
                "languages": [],
                "phone_number": ""
            }
        ],
        "logo": "logo address"
    }
]



How can I show a slot for each one of this company name in dropdown like this?
imagine this in dropdown:

company name is similar for each lane and also the avatar but the staff name and last name should be different under each line ,
I used my code and I just see the company name only how can I render the staff names and last names too ?

to access the data you want in the slot use item.raw e.g. item.raw.staff, but also you have only one dropdown option which is the entire company object, which contains a staff array. if you want a different staff member for each dropdown option then the v-combobox items prop should be just the staff array, not the entire company object. if company name is needed for each option, refactor the staff array so that company is another property like id or name

after a lots of time working with data I finally found it :


 <v-combobox
            v-model="select"
            v-model:search="search"
            :items="combinedCompanyStaffList"
            item-title="displayText"
            item-value="staffId"
            density="compact"
            label="Start chat withs"
            variant="outlined"
            bg-color="navbar"
            hide-details
            single-line
            @input="startConversation"
          >
            <template #item="{ index, props, item }">
              <v-list-item v-bind="props" :key="index" @click="createRoom(item)">
                <div class='flex flex-col gap-y-1'>
                  <!-- Staff Name -->
                  <span class='text-sm text-gray-100'>{{ item.staffName }}</span>
                  <!-- Company Name -->
                  <span class='text-sm text-gray-100'>{{ item.companyName }}</span>
                </div>
              </v-list-item>
            </template>
          </v-combobox>



And I made a data as a computed property and changed the shape of data :


const combinedCompanyStaffList = computed(() => {
  return companyList.value.flatMap(company =>
    company.staff.map(staffMember => ({
      staffId: staffMember.id, // Unique staff ID
      staffName: `${staffMember.name} ${staffMember.last_name}`, // Full staff name
      companyName: company.company_name, // Company name
      displayText: `${staffMember.name} ${staffMember.last_name} - ${company.company_name}`, // Text to display in combobox
      logo: company.logo
    }))
  );
});



No I have the data to make my custom slot in v-combobox
